# data annotations in MVC 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

Even after removing the required attribute why am i getting "The date of Birth is required" Error message? Is it because of any other attributes? How can i change it? I am just checking that incase if some one puts up unusual age, i can find it.

```
namespace ProjectCrux.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int studentId { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        [DateOfBirth(MinAge = 15, MaxAge = 90, ErrorMessage = "Too young or too old???")]
        public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }


        public string salt { get; set; }
    } 


    /* 
     * Attribute to validate date of birth within a range
     */
    public class DateOfBirthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public int MinAge { get; set; }
        public int MaxAge { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return true;

            var val = (DateTime)value;

            if (val.AddYears(MinAge) > DateTime.Now)
                return false;

            return (val.AddYears(MaxAge) > DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it nullable.

```
public DateTime? dateOfBirth { get; set; }
```